# Convert nested dictionary within JSON from a string

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have JSON data that I loaded that appears to have a bit of a messy data structure where nested dictionaries are wrapped in single quotes and recognized as a string, rather than a single dictionary which I can loop through. What is the best way to drop the single quotes from the key-value property ('value').

Provided below is an example of the structure:

```
for val in json_data:
    print(val)


{'id': 'status6',
   'title': 'Estimation',
   'text': '> 2 days',
   'type': 'color',
   'value': '{"index":14,"post_id":null,"changed_at":"2020-06-12T09:04:58.659Z"}',
   'name': 'Internal: online course'},
  {'id': 'date',
   'title': 'Deadline',
   'text': '2020-06-26',
   'type': 'date',
   'value': '{"date":"2020-06-26","changed_at":"2020-06-12T11:33:37.195Z"}',
   'name': 'Internal: online course'},
  {'id': 'tags',
   'title': 'Tags',
   'text': 'Internal',
   'type': 'tag',
   'value': '{"tag_ids":[3223513]}',
   'name': 'Internal: online course'},
```

If I add a nested look targeting ['value'], it loops by character and not key-value pair in the dictionary.

Comment: `JSON.parse` them.

Comment: loop over the objects and parse the value of `value`?

Comment: Try `eval()` when you encounter dictionary within quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `json.loads` to convert string to dict

```
import json

json_data = [{'id': 'status6',
   'title': 'Estimation',
   'text': '> 2 days',
   'type': 'color',
   'value': '{"index":14,"post_id":null,"changed_at":"2020-06-12T09:04:58.659Z"}',
   'name': 'Internal: online course'},
  {'id': 'date',
   'title': 'Deadline',
   'text': '2020-06-26',
   'type': 'date',
   'value': '{"date":"2020-06-26","changed_at":"2020-06-12T11:33:37.195Z"}',
   'name': 'Internal: online course'},
  {'id': 'tags',
   'title': 'Tags',
   'text': 'Internal',
   'type': 'tag',
   'value': '{"tag_ids":[3223513]}',
   'name': 'Internal: online course'}]


# the result is a Python dictionary:
for val in json_data:
    print(json.loads(val['value']))
```

this should be work!!